# maintaining list effectively

Tags: algorithm, list, collections

I have a huge list. I can add/rearrange/remove items from this list.
Since the list is really bug, I don't want to store the snapshot of entire list anywhere in the system.
Instead I maintain a xml file to keep track of items that are added/moved.

Each item is associated with `index and change order`.
Def- `Change order:` order in which item is added/moved.
Def- `Index:` index at which item is added/moved.

So now whenever I need to display the list, I'll have my original list and xml file. I'll use xml files, I'll add/move items according to the change order.

Whenever I want to move/delete any item from list, I have to change the indexes of other items.

for this I used simple code:

```
for each item in list: 
    If item's change order > removed/moved item's change order:
        Do Item's CO = item's CO - 1
        If item's index > removed item's index  (This index is not actual index, 
                                                 is the index where we  inserted
                                                 /moved the item. Item's actual 
                                                 index can be different, because
                                                 of the movements of other items 
                                                 in the list)
            Do Item's index = item's index - 1
```

This code is failing in many cases.  For  ex.

Original List ( S, D, G, Y, U, I)

in my xml I have

```
X: (newly added) CO 1, index 5
Giving me: (S, D, G, Y, X, U, I)
Y: (already in list at position 4) CO 2 index 6
Giving me: (S, D, G, X, Y, U, I)
```

after this in my actual list:

```
X: pos: 4 
Y: pos: 5
```

Now I want to remove X. according to code
    Y: CO 1 index 5

Applying this to original list: (S, D, G, U, Y, I)

which is wrong!

Is there any correct existing algorithm for this type of requirement?

Thanks....

---

I cant store the file in database. There is a possibility by which the original list can change. For ex. base list is (p,q,r). And xml is: (add x to 2nd pos, add y to 4th pos, move Q to 4th pos). But there is a possibility by which my base list can become (w,p,r,g,h) and I have to use the same xml file (add x to 2nd pos, add y to 4th pos, move Q to 4th pos) so that the new elements get added at there expected position. If some item (like Q) is not in base list, but is in xml, I have to ignore that xml node.

Comment: So, the list is huge and you don't want to store it because it's really big. But you want to store all the changes you make to it. With *XML*. I don't think that will help making it any smaller.

Comment: Thank you for reply.  I cant store the file in database. Its not only because the list is huge. There is a possibility by which the original list can change. For ex. base list is (p,q,r). And xml is: (add x to 2nd pos, add y to 4th pos, move Q to 4th pos). But there is a possibility by which my base list can become (w,p,r,g,h) and I have to use the same xml file (add x to 2nd pos, add y to 4th pos, move Q to 4th pos) so that the new elements get added at there expected position. If some item (like Q) is not in base list, but is in xml, I have to ignore that xml node.

Comment: So it's not really about the list, it's about those instructions? What exactly is the question then?

Comment: The problem is when I move/remove some item for the second time, I have to change the change orders and indexes of other items in xml. It works in most of the scenarios but not all. I described one such failed scenario above.

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't address the question of your algorithm, but could you store your list in a database?  You could use a file-based DBMS such as SQLite, which is very simple to use.

It seems to me that the operations you are describing could be easily done with some simple SQL statements.

Edit: MySQL changed to SQLite

Comment: Thank you for your reply, but I cant store the file in database. There is a possibility by which the original list can change. For ex. base list is (p,q,r). And xml is: (add x to 2nd pos, add y to 4th pos). But there is a possibility by which my base list can become (w,p,r,g,h) and I have to use the same xml file (add x to 2nd pos, add y to 4th pos, move Q to 4th pos) so that  the new elements get added at there expected position. If some item (like Q) is not in base list, but is in xml, I have to ignore that xml node.

Comment: I would not say that MySQL is that simple to use if you have to install it and administer it. For this sort of straightforward list you are better off with something like gdb or SQLite. Both are self contained and do not require any server process.

Comment: Ah, my apologies.  SQLite is what I was thinking of.

Comment: Regarding @Michael's comment, and to help with your Googling (gdb is also the name of the GNU Debugger), gdb is the embedded Firebird server. If you're on .NET, there's also SQL Compact Edition.

Comment: Thank you again, but I can't use SQLite even if it solves the problem. I have to implement the solution in the technologies that are already in use.

Comment: You haven't specified what technologies are in use. For instance most Linux systems come with some database capabilities installed like gdbm and bsddb.

Comment: The project is developed in VB6. Can't run it on Linux.